# Fluent NHibernate enforce Not Nullable on Foreign Key Reference

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, automapping

Just getting my feet wet with some Fluent NHibernate AutoMap conventions, and ran into something I couldn't figure out. I assume I'm just not looking in the right place...
Basically trying to enforce NOT-NULL on the "many" side of the one to many relationship.
It seems, using the automapping, it always makes the parent property Id nullable in the database.

I did some searching on StackOverFlow and found similar questions, but nothing relating to AutoMapping and Conventions though (unless I missed it).

Quick example...

```
public class Group    // One Group
{
    public Group() { this.Jobs = new List<Job>(); }
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Job> Jobs { get; protected set; }
}

public class Job    // Has many Jobs
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    // Trying to make this field not-nullable in the database.
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
}
```

I thought I'd be able to just create a convention like...

```
public class OneToManyConvention : IHasOneConvention
{
    public void Apply(IOneToOneInstance instance)
    {
        // Nullable() isn't a valid method...
        instance.Not.Nullable();   
    }
}
```

But it seems IOneToOnInstance doesn't have a Nullable() method. I can do this if I create a Map file for Job, but trying to avoid any Map files and stick with auto-mapping.

I came across this [link on the Fluent group list](http://groups.google.com/group/fluent-nhibernate/browse_thread/thread/b16f5cea501ec97e) describing something similar.

Which describes something like this...

```
public class NotNullPropertyConvention : IPropertyConvention
{
    public bool Accept(IProperty target)
    {
            return true;
    }
    public void Apply(IProperty target)
    {
            target.Not.Nullable();
    }
}
```

But that raises the questions of...
1) How would I determine IProperty to be a Job (or any child property that is a link back to the parent)

2) It made a mention on that page that using this would override my manual overrides, eg. if a very specific property link needed to be NULL. Which would be an issue (if it's still an issue, but can't test without figuring out #1 first)

Any ideas on this? Am I just missing something?

---

**Update 1**

Still no go. Even the following still doesn't enforce Not-Nullable in the database schema...

```
public class FluentConvention : IPropertyConvention
{
    public void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Not.Nullable();
    }
}
```

It does for all of the other fields though...

/shrug

Any ideas?

---

**Update 2**

While this isn't the answer I was looking for, I did find a work around...
I was using NHibernate Validator assembly, and within that assembly there is a [NotNull] attribute. If I decorated my class with the Validator attribute, and associated the ValidationEngine to NHibernate before the schema creation, it would tag the FK database column as Not-Nullable.

```
public class Job    // Has many Jobs
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    [NHibernate.Validator.Constraints.NotNull]
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
}
```

If anyone needs the full code for the NHibernate + ValidationEngine initialization, just let me know.
Still looking for a way to do it using the pure mapping convention route though if anyone has any info...

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can override the auto-mapped properties as part of your AutoMap in Fluenttly.Configure().

So you can do this:

```
.Override<Job>(map => map.References(x => x.Group).Not.Nullable())
```

It's not exactly convenient if you have a lot of classes that need this though.

**Edit:** 
You can also specify the override in a class that implements IAutoMappingOverride like so:

```
    public class JobMappingOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<Job>
    {
            public void Override(AutoMapping<Job> mapping)
            {
                    mapping.References(x => x.Group).Not.Nullable();
            }
    }
```

and include it like so:

```
    .UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<JobMappingOverride>()
```

This would keep your fluent configuration a little cleaner.

Comment: I don't have the source on hand to test this answer. If anyone else does, and it works, please up-vote as a solution, and I'll tag it. Thanks.

Comment: @Steve Yes, this _is_ the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `IPropertyConvention` is only called on simple properties of your classes. If your property references another class, you need to use `IReferenceConvention` too.

Try this:

```
public class FluentConvention : IPropertyConvention, IReferenceConvention  
{      
    public void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
    {          
        instance.Not.Nullable();      
    }

    public void Apply(IManyToOneInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Not.Nullable();
    }
}
```