# How do I specify a property as required (NOT NULLABLE)?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

I am trying my hand at NHibernate's built-in mapping by code. I've got it mostly working now. My problem is how do I configure which properties on my objects are required in the database within the convention? I'm guessing this would be some sort of attribute markup?

I know if I do the mappings by hand, I can configure them as required, but how do I do this with conventions?

Comment: The following post might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605930/fluent-nhibernate-automap-convention-for-not-null-field -- I recommend looking at all of the answers, rather than just the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks, but this applies to to Fluent mapping, not the mapping-by-code. I understand I could write my own attribute and logic to handle this with the configuration possible - but I thought this might be built in or already done by someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use nullable types, for example in the class,

```
public class Foo
{
   public int Bar { get; set; }
   public int? baz { get; set; }
}
```

Bar will not be nullable, while Baz will be nullable in the db when use mapping by code.

Comment: What about things like References? For example: `public MyClass Test {get; set;}` . This defaults to Nullable because a class is nullable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791582/fluent-nhibernate-enforce-not-nullable-on-foreign-key-reference, try using automapping override              public class JobMappingOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<Job>
    {
            public void Override(AutoMapping<Job> mapping)
            {
                    mapping.References(x => x.Group).Not.Nullable();
            }
    }

Comment: That's for Fluent NHibernate

Comment: Automapping is not Fluent NHibernate, http://fluentnhibernate.wikia.com/wiki/Auto_mapping